# how to use GroupBy and Where Clause in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Please am trying to retrieve data from a joined table in a database using GroupBy and Where clause in laravel. i get errors if i add the `groupBy`. it works without the GroupBy but i want to sort the data after retrieving.

this is what i have, someone should kindly assist me

```
public function showResult($std_id)
{
    $results = DB::table('students')
        ->select('*')
        ->join('results', 'students.std_id', 'results.student_results_id')
        ->where('student_results_id', $std_id)
        ->groupBy('results.academic_year')
        ->get();
    $studentprofilePage = Student::find($std_id);
    if (empty($studentprofilePage)) {
        return redirect('/user');
    }

    return view('resultsdisplay', [
        'results' => $results,
        'studentresultsprofile' => $studentprofilePage,
    ]);
}
```

am getting this error

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'smgt.students.std_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `students` inner join `results` on `students`.`std_id` = `results`.`student_results_id` where `student_results_id` = 4662416 group by `results`.`academic_year`)
```

Comment: You want to sort... means you want to have the data sorted by academic_year??

Comment: I want to group data by academic_year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, What I've understood from the code, is that you need to group results by the academic year and then join it to the students table. so I'll suggest

```
DB::table('students')
                  ->select('*')
                  ->join('results', function ($join) {
                       $join->on('students.std_id', '=', 'results.student_results_id')->groupBy('results.academic_year'); 
                   })
                  ->where('student_results_id', $std_id)
                  ->get();
```

something like this.

Answer (score -1):

To build on `mohammad.kaab` answer, you should be able to use `Student` model to build this query, which in result will make your code cleaner. I would also recommend utilising Laravel's type hints, `showResult(Student $student)`, Laravel will fetch `Student` for you in the background and if a student was not found then 404 is returned.

So you should be able to do something similar to below:

```
public function showResult(Student $student)
{
    $results = $student->results()
            ->groupBy('results.academic_year');  
            ->get(); 

    return view('resultsdisplay', [
        'results' => $results,
        'studentresultsprofile' => $student,
    ]);
}
```